# What is best practice for many to many relationships in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dto

For my ASP.NET Web API, I have a many-to-many relationship similar to this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookTag> BookTags { get; set; }
}  

public class BookTag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookTag> BookTags { get; set; }
}
```

Now I created DTOs and controllers for all 3 but this means:

- I can't create a `Tag` when creating a `Book`. I have to create the `Book` **first** and then after make `POST` request to `BookTags` by passing both the `TagId` and `BookId`.

  I have a POST Dto for `Book` but I'm unsure what to put in there. I am able to get the `BookTags` through the response in a `Book`.
- I now have to create 3 controllers which is a pain along with the repositories, DTOs etc. (flexible but more stuff to maintain)

Is it best practice to have it like this? I don't mind the approach but would like to know if there is any easier way to associate books with tags.

I am hoping for an easier way to maintain this relationship and possibly make a `POST` request simpler to add tags

Comment: *"I can't create a tag when creating a Book"*  - ehh really? you can add both new tag and book into the `DbContext` then call `SaveChanges` no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is any issue in creating a `Tag` or a `Book` Separately. The relationship between them is maintained in `BookTag` table (which makes them independent from each other).
The approach you have used here to handle the many to many relationship is pretty common and used often to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to prescribe guidance without knowing how the client is architected but while making some assumptions I think you've overcomplicated it. You should be able to achieve this with a single API method and a single call.

Assuming we're talking about an EntityFramework implementation, I would do it like this instead, `BookTags` is just a lookup table:

```cs
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}  

public class BookTag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BookDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

If you were using Mediator for example:

```cs
/* query handler */
var book = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.Id);
var tags = db.Tags.Where(x => x.BookId == book.Id)

var bookDto = Mapper.Map<BookDto>(book);
bookDto.Tags = tags.Select(x => Mapper.Map<BookTag>(x));

return bookDto;



/* create command handler */
var book = Mapper.Map<Book>(request.BookDto);
var tags = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Tag>>(request.BookDto.Tags);

// transaction ensures if anything fails between Begin & Commit, everything is rolled back
using var dbTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction();

db.Books.Add(book);
db.Tags.Add(tags);
db.SaveChanges();

db.BookTags.AddRange(tags.Select(x => new BookTag { BookId = book.Id, TagId = x.Id);

dbTransaction.CommitTransaction();
```